# Power Apps - Search based on combo box

Tags: powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

New to Power Apps here.

I'm querying a SharePoint list from Power Apps. My list (DocList) has a column with document titles and another one with labels. Each document can include more than one label separated by commas. Example:

```
DocTitle    Labels
Doc 1       Label A
Doc 2       Label B
Doc 3       Label A; Label C
Doc 4       Label B; Label C; Label D
Doc 5       Label A; Label D
Doc 6       Label D
```

I've created a combo box showing the distinct values of Labels:

I'm showing the content of my list in a table and then filtering it. How can I filter it based on the values selected in the combo box?

If I use something like:

```
Filter(DocList, IsEmpty(LabelCombo.SelectedItems) || IsBlank(LabelCombo.SelectedItems) || 'Labels' in LabelCombo.SelectedItems)
```

It will work for Doc 1, Doc 2 and Doc 6. However, not for the rest, as they include multiple labels.

It works if I make the combo box searchable, but I don't want to enable this feature:

```
Filter(DocList, IsEmpty(LabelCombo.SelectedItems) || IsBlank(LabelCombo.SelectedItems) || LabelCombo.SearchText in 'Labels')
```

The following shows an error:

```
Filter(DocList, IsEmpty(LabelCombo.SelectedItems) || IsBlank(LabelCombo.SelectedItems) || UseCaseCombo.SelectedItems in 'Labels')
```

Any tips on how to solve this?

Thanks!